# Errors only when I install the APK

Tags: android, android-install-apk, illegalaccessexception

I have a simple application made after udacity tutorial: https://classroom.udacity.com/courses/ud853.
Source code here: https://github.com/ionutincau/Vremea.

If I install the app through USB debugging mode (Run Option in Android Studio) it works fine, but if I "build APK" and install the built apk, the app crashes.

I have Internet Connection, but when I try to fetch data from http://api.openweathermap.org I get URL `Connection Error java.io.FileNotFoundException` . And, when I try to open Settings I get:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.ionut.vremea2, PID: 6850
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.ionut.vremea2/com.example.ionut.vremea2.SettingsActivity}: java.lang.IllegalAccessException:
```

I get the errors only if install the app from apk file

**SettingsActivity**

```
class SettingsActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);
    }
}
```

I am using this code to get data from internet:

```
    protected String[] doInBackground(String... params) {
        if (params.length == 0) {
            return null;
        }

        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        String forecastJsonStr = null;

        String format = "json";
        String units = "metric";
        int numDays = 7;
        String api_key = "my_key"; // I have a valid code in my app

        try {
            // Construct the URL for the OpenWeatherMap query
            final String FORECAST_BASE_URL = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?";
            final String QUERY_PARAM = "id";
            final String FORMAT_PARAM = "mode";
            final String UNITS_PARAM = "units";
            final String DAYS_PARAM = "cnt";
            final String APPID_PARAM = "APPID";

            // Construct the URL for the OpenWeatherMap query
            Uri builtUri = Uri.parse(FORECAST_BASE_URL).buildUpon()
                    .appendQueryParameter(QUERY_PARAM, params[0])
                    .appendQueryParameter(FORMAT_PARAM, format)
                    .appendQueryParameter(UNITS_PARAM, units)
                    .appendQueryParameter(DAYS_PARAM, Integer.toString(numDays))
                    .appendQueryParameter(APPID_PARAM, api_key)
                    .build();

            URL url = new URL(builtUri.toString());

            // Create the request to OpenWeatherMap, and open the connection
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlConnection.connect();

            // Read the input stream into a String
            InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            // ... do something
```

Comment: Show the relevant code.

Comment: Source code here: https://github.com/ionutincau/Vremea.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with creating of the activities is because you need to have their classes public.

```
public class SettingsActivity extends Activity {
}
```

For the filenotfound you can open the link in the browser and see the actual response:
{"cod":"502","message":"Error: Not found city"}

you need to configure it to get a proper response, but you should also handle the error responses, by checking the urlConnection.getResponseCode() against HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK. In case of failure you would get more information on urlConnection.getResponseMessage() or on the stream urlConnection.getErrorStream().

```
if (urlConnection.getResposeCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
...
} else {
...
}
```